# Is it possible to change the output for each \excludecomment or \includecomment (comments package)?

Tags: external-files, auxiliary-files, comments

I am trying to avoid modularizing a document into separate files (because it gets translated into 10 languages!) Instead, I am trying my luck with the `comments` package.

Let's say I have three software manuals for three variants of the program:

1. appname-demo.tex
2. appname-pro.tex
3. appname.tex

## Problem

The problem seems to me that overlapping includes and excludes would both write to `comment.cut`. This would cause the file to possibly be empty during an embedded (sequential) read.

From the `comment.sty` source code:

> The comment environments use two auxiliary commands. You can get nifty special effects by redefining them. [...]
>   `\def\CommentCutFile{comment.cut}`

## Attempt

*Does not typeset.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\IfSubStr{\jobname}{\detokenize{pro}}
  {\includecomment{include-pro}} % TRUE, so show pro stuff
  {\excludecomment{include-pro}}
\IfSubStr{\jobname}{\detokenize{demo}}
  {\excludecomment{exclude-demo}} % TRUE, so hide stuff
  {\includecomment{exclude-demo}} 

%\specialcomment{include-pro-functionality}% Attempt at changing `\CommentCutFile`
%  {\begingroup\def\CommentCutFile{include-pro.cut}}{\endgroup}
%\specialcomment{hide-in-demo}% Attempt at changing `\CommentCutFile`
%  {\begingroup\def\CommentCutFile{exclude-demo.cut}}{\endgroup}


\begin{document}
\section{Normal Functions}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{exclude-demo}
\section{Paid-Version Only Functions}
\lipsum[2]
\end{exclude-demo}

\begin{include-pro}
\section{Professional Functions}
\lipsum[3]
\end{include-pro}

% Overlapping Comments Test
\begin{exclude-demo}
\section{Paid-Version Only Functions}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{include-pro}
\subsection{Pro-Version Only Embedded}  
\end{include-pro}
\end{exclude-demo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't nest comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to close this question. I am going to go with Ulrike Fischer and say that **you can't [currently] nest comments**.

It might be possible by creating separate files for each nested comment, but this would require more time than its worth. Perhaps someday...